# How to solve a block matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two linear systems as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf K \mathbf X+\mathbf A ^{\text T}\mathbf v=\mathbf O_{{(\hat{m}+1)\times 1}} \quad (1)\\
\mathbf A \mathbf X=\mathbf P \qquad \quad \quad(2) 
\end{cases}
$$
which could be written in block matrix form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf K & \mathbf A ^{\text T}\\
\mathbf A & \mathbf O_{{(m+1)\times (m+1)}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf X \\
\mathbf v 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf O_{{(\hat{m}+1)\times 1}} \\
\mathbf P 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where,  $\mathbf O$ is a matrix filled with $0$s, and

$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf K=\left(k_{i,j}\right)_{(\hat{m}+1) \times (\hat{m}+1)}\\
\mathbf A=\left(a_{i,j}\right)_{(m+1) \times (\hat{m}+1)}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
\mathbf X = [\mathbf x_0,\cdots,\mathbf x_{\hat{m}}]^{\mathbf T}\\
\mathbf P = [\mathbf p_0,\cdots,\mathbf p_m]^{\mathbf T}\\
\mathbf v = [\mathbf v_0,\cdots,\mathbf v_m]^{\mathbf T}\\
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
\mathbf x_i=(x_{i1},x_{i2},x_{i3})\\
\mathbf p_i=(p_{i1},p_{i2},p_{i3})
\end{cases}
$$

#### My trial 1

With the help of Eq.(1)

$$
\mathbf X=-\mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T}\mathbf v\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf A\mathbf X=-\mathbf A \mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T}\mathbf v\\
$$

Then, by means of Eq.(2)

$$
\Rightarrow \mathbf P=-\mathbf A \mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T}\mathbf v\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf v=-(\mathbf A \mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T})^{-1}\mathbf P\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf X=\mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T}(\mathbf A \mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T})^{-1}\mathbf P
$$

#### My trial 2

Construting the following block matrix

$$
\mathbf M=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf K & \mathbf A ^{\text T}\\
\mathbf A & \mathbf O
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \mathbf b=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf O \\
\mathbf P 
\end{bmatrix}\\
\Rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf X \\
\mathbf v 
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathbf M^{-1}\mathbf b
$$

#### Test in Mathematica

I implemented the trial 1 and trial 2, respectively. I discovered that

$$\mathbf X=\mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T}(\mathbf A \mathbf K^{-1}\mathbf A ^{\text T})^{-1}\mathbf P$$
gives the **wrong** result

While

$$\mathbf M^{-1}\mathbf b$$ gives the **right** result. Unfortunately, the block matrix $\mathbf M$ is ill-conditioned.

Comment: Hi. You will probably also need to mention that $\bf O$ is a matrix filled with 0s? But is it both a zero vector and a zero matrix? You use it in both the vector and the matrix.

Comment: @mathreadler OK, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: aren't KX and $A^Tv$ incompatible?

Comment: @JonMark  $\mathbf K_{(\hat m + 1)\times(\hat m + 1)} \mathbf X_{(\hat m + 1)\times 1} +\mathbf A ^{\text T}_{(\hat m + 1)\times(m + 1)} \mathbf v_{(m + 1)\times 1} =\mathbf O_{{(\hat{m}+1)\times 1}}$

Comment: yes but $x_i=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $v_i$ is just a scalar

Comment: @mathreadler In fact, the above linear system comes from this [paper](http://dx.doi.org.sci-hub.cc/10.1016/S0010-4485(03)00040-X). See section 3.2. In addtion, the trial 2 can solve the right result. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, well the lagrange multipliers may be unnecessary in this case. Just  derive the normal equations to make the constraint an extra term in the minimization. Or maybe you can try a pseudoinverse ${\bf M}^{\dagger}$ if the inverse ${\bf M}^{-1}$ is not stable.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for your suggestions. I will have a trial:)